# Two seemingly identical strings behave differently

Tags: scala

Look at the following code which compiles nicely:

```
trait ParserError
trait Parser[+A]{
  def run[A](input:A):Either[ParserError, A]
}

object Parser{
  case object ParserErrorImpl extends ParserError

  def string(s:String):Parser[String] = new Parser[String]{
    def run[String](input:String) = {
      if(input == s) Right(input) else Left(ParserErrorImpl)
    }
  }
}

object Runner{
  import Parser._
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
    println(string("aaa").run("aaa"))
  }
}
```

When I change `Right(input)` to `Right(s)` it brings a compilation error:

```
Error:(13, 58) type mismatch;
 found   : s.type (with underlying type String)
 required: String
    def run[String](input:String) = if(input == s) Right(s) else Left(ParserErrorImpl)
                                                         ^
```

Could you explain why this happens since it is not completely clear to me?

Comment: Tip: no need to update the question with the answer (actually, it's just confusing for future readers) - just mark the best answer as "accepted" and/or upvote the best answers.

Comment: Accounted. Removed that update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are shadowing your type parameter A by (re)defining it in your run method. Make trait Parser parameterized by type A and use that type as the run method's parameter type.

Here's the fixed version:

```
trait ParserError
trait Parser[A]{
  def run(input:A):Either[ParserError, A] // <-- not run[A] !!!
}

object Parser{
  case object ParserErrorImpl extends ParserError

  def string(s:String):Parser[String] = new Parser[String]{
    def run(input:String) = {
      if(input == s) Right(input) else Left(ParserErrorImpl)
    }
  }
}
```

Reason for this is the fact that you can't set the type of implemented method to String. You wanted to do this, but what actually happens is that "String" is just another identifier for the method type; it could have also been "Strings" or "Stringozoid". See answer by @Tzach Zohar for richer explanation.

Also, I removed covariance to keep things simpler, but you probably want to keep it so you need to do the good old lower-bound trick. Check out answer by @Leif Ericson for full solution on this.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: This solves the issue, but it still doesn't explain why it failed - the shadowing itself isn't it

Answer (score 3):

When overriding a type-parameterized method, you can't "set" the type to be `String` using `def methodName[String]` - whatever you "pass" as the type parameter isn't really going to be interpreted as the parameter *value*, but rather as a *new parameter **name***. In this case, in:

```
def string(s:String):Parser[String] = new Parser[String]{
  def run[String](input:String) = { 
    if(input == s) Right(input) else Left(ParserErrorImpl)
  }
}
```

When you write `def run[String]`, you're creating a **new** type parameter **named** "String", not an overriding method that would use `scala.Predef.String`. Now, `input` is guaranteed to have that type (whatever it is, could be Int!), but `s` isn't.

To see this - try using a different name instead of "String" in your original, compiling version - and see that it still compiles:

```
def string(s:String):Parser[String] = new Parser[String]{
  def run[SomeUnknownType](input:SomeUnknownType) = {
    if(input == s) Right(input) else Left(ParserErrorImpl)
  }
}
```

To fix this - in this case, you can just get rid of the *method's* type parameter and use the *class's* parameter as suggested by @slouc - you named them both `A`, but these are two different parameters.

Comment: could you review the code under the UPDATE if this is a nicer version. I will remove then this UPDATE section. For me it is important to also understand how to make this trait covariant and I think it is now ok.

Comment: Yeah, the update looks right, since it uses a new type parameter bound to be a supertype of String `[B >: String]` instead of using `[String]` directly, which doesn't actually bound the type to be anything...

Answer (score 2):

You actually can keep the covariance while still making the code compile:

```
trait ParserError

trait Parser[+A] {
  def run[B >: A](input: B): Either[ParserError, B]
}

object Parser {

  case object ParserErrorImpl extends ParserError

  def string(s: String): Parser[String] = new Parser[String] {
    def run[B >: String](input: B) = {
      if (input == s) Right(s) else Left(ParserErrorImpl)
    }
  }
}

object Runner {

  import Parser._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(string("aaa").run("aaa"))
  }
}
```